# Triggers Mutually Exclusive Boolean Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have two boolean (bit) fields that I want to remain mutually exclusive. They can both be false, but if one gets set to true the other must be set to false.

I tried to create 2 triggers but wound up creating an infinite loop (that stopped after 32 iterations). Apparently they trigger each other. Here is the code I tried:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TriggerNameA
ON dbo.TableName
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(FieldA)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.TableName
        SET FieldB = 
            CASE WHEN dbo.TableName.FieldA = 1 
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END
        FROM dbo.TableName INNER JOIN inserted ON dbo.TableName.ID = inserted.ID
    END;
;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TriggerNameB
ON dbo.TableName
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(FieldB)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.TableName
        SET FieldA = 
            CASE WHEN dbo.TableName.FieldB = 1 
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END
        FROM dbo.TableName INNER JOIN inserted ON dbo.TableName.ID = inserted.ID
    END;
;
GO
```

Any idea how to avoid the infinite loop?

Comment: The best option is to fix you table design and store the data in a single column instead of 2. If you need a trigger, use only 1 trigger. But what if both columns are updated at the same time? Which takes precidence?

Comment: Why not use a `CONSTRAINT` to not allow them both be `1`? Also, I don't think you understand what `IF UPDATE()` does; it does *not* check to see if the value of a column has changed.

Comment: Essentially you have 3 states `neither` `A` `B`, so you can use a single `tinyint` column with a check constraint `(State >= 0 AND State <= 2)`

Comment: The triggers you created don't quite implement the rule:: "They can both be false, but if one gets set to true the other must be set to false.." When one column is set to `1` then you set the other to `0`,, but when a column is set to `0` you _force_ the other column to `1` rather than leaving the value unchanged.. Extra credit for using a double statement terminator (`;;`)..

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. The CONSTRAINT does not work because I don't want to simply not allow both to be true. I want the other one to flip to false when one is set to true.

Comment: HABO - thank you for pointing out that I'm also forcing one to be true when the other one is set to false. I'll fix that aspect of it. But I still need to figure out a way to not trigger each other.

Charlieface - I appreciate the idea of using a tinyint instead of a bit, but this is already an established database with a working front end. I was hoping to just get them to maintain the state the way it is.

Comment: @JohnOsmond perhaps an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER would work better and give you more control, they are not recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Check constraint removes the need for a trigger:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/941bc9/6)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table MyTable
(
  ID int Identity,
  FieldA bit,
  FieldB bit,
  CONSTRAINT Chk_Fields CHECK (FieldA <> 1 OR FieldB <> 1)
)

INSERT INTO MyTable(FieldA, FieldB)
VALUES (0,0),(0,1),(1,0)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from MyTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/941bc9/6/0)**:

```
| ID | FieldA | FieldB |
|----|--------|--------|
|  1 |  false |  false |
|  2 |  false |   true |
|  3 |   true |  false |
```

**Query 2**:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(FieldA, FieldB)
VALUES (1,1),(0,1),(1,0)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/941bc9/6/1)**:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "Chk_Fields". The conflict occurred in database "db_18_941bc9", table "dbo.MyTable".
```

**Query 3**:

```
UPDATE MyTable
  SET FieldB = 1
WHERE ID = 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/941bc9/6/2)**:

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "Chk_Fields". The conflict occurred in database "db_18_941bc9", table "dbo.MyTable".
```

> EDIT As @CharlieFace mentions in his comment, the equivalent check
> constraint of `(FieldA = 0 OR FieldB = 0)` is more readable

Comment: Wouldn't `(FieldA = 0 OR FieldB = 0)` or `NOT (FieldA = 1 AND FieldB = 1)` be more readable?

Comment: @Charlieface agreed, I'll update

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this does not do it for me. I'm not trying to simply not allow them both to be true. I want them to actively flip each other without throwing an error. When one goes true the other goes false.

Comment: @JohnOsmond what happens if I issue an update to set both to be true? e.g. UPDATE TableName SET FieldA = 1, FieldB = 1

Comment: @SteveFord, I'm not sure but in my case the only way these flags ever get set is from an Access form. So when the user checks one box the other goes off (if the other is on in the first place.)

Comment: @SteveFord - okay I just ran your experiment. It turns them both off. LOL! It's all good tho. As I said it's really just to keep the user interface state maintained and now that I have the where clause in place it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER to ensure that on an UPDATE only one of the fields is set to 1. I have made a decision in the trigger that if FieldA in the virtual INSERTED table is set to 1 then I set FieldB to zero:

**SetUp**

```
create table MyTable
(
  ID int Identity,
  FieldA bit,
  FieldB bit
)

    CREATE TRIGGER TriggerNameA ON MyTable
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE
    AS
  IF UPDATE(FieldA)
  BEGIN
     MERGE [MyTable] AS t1
     USING (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AS t2
       ON t1.ID = t2.ID
     WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET t1.[FieldA] = t2.FieldA, 
                t1.[FieldB] = CASE WHEN t2.FieldA = 1 THEN 0 ELSE t2.FieldB END;
  END
  ELSE IF UPDATE(FieldB)
  BEGIN
     MERGE [MyTable] AS t1
     USING (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AS t2
       ON t1.ID = t2.ID
     WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET t1.[FieldB] = t2.FieldB, 
                t1.[FieldA] = CASE WHEN t2.FieldB = 1 THEN 0 ELSE t2.FieldA END;
  END;
  -- Add Else for cases where FieldA & FieldB weren't updated if required
```

**Result 1**

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(FieldA, FieldB)
VALUES (0,0),(0,1),(1,0);

SELECT * FROM MyTable

ID  FieldA  FieldB
1   False   False
2   False   True
3   True    False
```

**Result 2**

```
UPDATE MyTable
 SET FieldB = 1
WHERE ID = 1

SELECT * FROM MyTable

ID  FieldA  FieldB
1   False   True
2   False   True
3   True    False
```

**Result 3**

```
UPDATE MyTable
 SET FieldB = 1
WHERE ID = 3

SELECT * FROM MyTable

ID  FieldA  FieldB
1   False   True
2   False   True
3   False   True
```

**Result 4**

```
UPDATE MyTable
 SET FieldA = 1
WHERE ID = 2

SELECT * FROM MyTable

ID  FieldA  FieldB
1   False   True
2   True    False
3   True    False
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=48cc4a0610f03f8e68f065443d6712ff)

> Edited to Update fieldA or FieldB depending on what column is updated
> in the UPDATE statement

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, but it looks like result 3 gives the wrong result. If you set FieldB to 1 on record 3, then record 3 should yield False True. Yours is the other way around. Not sure if you saw my response where I added a where clause to the update block. That works for what I'm after.

Comment: Also, meant to say, thanks for the lesson. I didn't know about 'instead of update' - that's good stuff. Never saw 'when matched then'. Really useful stuff.

Comment: @JohnOsmond It doesn't update FieldB because FieldA is 1 in the Inserted table, you could wrap the merge with an If UPDATE() statement for each field then an 3rd update that just merges without changing the 2 fields

Comment: @JohnOsmond updated to fix result 3, simpler to me as only have one trigger with no possibility of recursion

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I apologize for my previous answer, but I'm sure I got it now. Thanks to @DB<>Fiddle for pointing out that it still was experiencing recursion (or nesting, not sure).

So I used the trigger_nestlevel function. Tested and now (finally) it works:

```
create table MyTable
(
  ID int Identity,
  FieldA bit,
  FieldB bit
)
go

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.Trigger1
ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() = 1
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(FieldA)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET dbo.MyTable.FieldB = 0
            FROM dbo.MyTable INNER JOIN inserted ON dbo.MyTable.ID = inserted.ID;
        END;
    END;
;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.Trigger2
ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() = 1
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(FieldB)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET dbo.MyTable.FieldA = 0
            FROM dbo.MyTable INNER JOIN inserted ON dbo.MyTable.ID = inserted.ID;
        END;
    END;
;
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable(FieldA, FieldB)
VALUES (0,0)

SELECT * FROM MyTable;
-- 0 0

UPDATE MyTable
SET FieldA = 1
WHERE ID = 1;

SELECT * FROM MyTable;
-- 1 0

UPDATE MyTable
SET FieldB = 1
WHERE ID = 1;

SELECT * FROM MyTable;
-- 0 1
```

Then I can go back and forth and they continue to switch the way I need. Whew!